# How to access a database from a regular class?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

Good day!
I need to create a method that will run every hour. My problem is complicated by the fact that this method has to work with a database.
I found a way to run the method every time, but how do I access the database from a normal class.

```
public DisconnectingUsers()
        {
            TimerCallback tm = new TimerCallback(disconnect);
            Timer timer = new Timer(tm, null, 0, 10000);
        }
        public void disconnect(object state)
        {
            //work with database
        }
```

The basic idea is for the method to run every hour and edit the database.

Comment: That depends on how you are scheduling the command to run every hour. You need to show us your code. Having said that, without any code, I would suggest you take a look at a tool like Hangfire as that will do scheduled jobs and allow you to inject an entity framework DbContext.

Comment: I see you have added your code to demonstrate how you are doing your scheduled method. Please note doing that is a really dangerous way to work in an ASP.NET environment. Web apps are meant to be called via an HTTP call, and once the request is done, all resources are cleaned up. You should not be using a timer like this. I strongly recommend looking at Hangfire as it will simplify this dramatically. It is a plugin for your ASP.NET Core app.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to use this plugin, but still tell me how to access the database from a regular class, or is such an action not possible?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "regular class", and even how you interact with your database. That is such a fundamental question that it is probably far better for you to run through some proper tutorials first.